# Attempted to call an undefined method named "remove" of class

Tags: symfony, symfony4

I'm trying to make a `DELETE methode` ( CRUD ) **Symfony 4.2** , like this :

```
/**
 * @Route("/delete/{id}", name="delete")
 * Method({"DELETE"})
 */
public function Delete(Request $request , $id)
{
    $etudiant = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository(Etudiant::class)->find($id);

    $entityManger = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $entityManger = $this->remove($etudiant);
    $entityManger = $this->flush();
    $response = new Response();
    $response->send();

    return $this->redirectToRoute('home');
}
```

But this errors displayed to me at my browser:

> **Attempted to call an undefined method named "remove" of class**;

Comment: What have you tried to debug the problem? Have you defined that `remove`  method in your class?

Comment: yes , i defined it in my class

Comment: Can you share the definition then?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The part of the multiple assignments is wrong. You have to invoke the methods on the entity manager, not `$this`.

```php
    $entityManger = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager(); // get once, use as much as you need

    $etudiant = $entityManger->getRepository(Etudiant::class)->find($id);
    $entityManger->remove($etudiant);
    $entityManger->flush($etudiant); // only flush this entity, you never know what else is going on in listeners and such. You don't want to flush other entities, if you can avoid as easily as here.

    // these two lines make little sense. You should return a response, which is the redirect. No need to "send" anything else...
    //$response = new Response();
    //$response->send();

    return $this->redirectToRoute('home');
```